# How can i calculate the percent of full moon on a given date?

Tags: date, delphi, math

I need to find the percentage of a full moon on a given date, but i can not figure out how to calculate this. My attempt to do this is wrong, because the percent of to day is about 96.9%. Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong in my delphi-code.

```
procedure TfrmLag.btnCalcClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  whatDate    : TDateTime;      // Now;
  lunarDays   : Double;        // 29.53058770576
  lunarSecs   : LongInt;        // lunarDays * (24*60*60);
  new2000     : TDateTime;      // 6.1 2000 18:14
  totalSecs   : LongInt;        // whatDate - new2000
  currSecs    : LongInt;        // totalSecs MOD lunarSecs
  currFrac    : Double;        // currSecs / lunarSecs
  currDays    : LongInt;        // currFrac * lunarDays
  perOfFull   : Double;
begin
  whatDate  := Now;
  lunarDays := 29.53058770576;
  lunarSecs := Round(lunarDays * (24*60*60));
  new2000   := EncodeDateTime(2000,1,6,18,14,00,000);
  totalSecs := SecondsBetween(whatDate, new2000);
  currSecs  := totalSecs MOD lunarSecs;
  currFrac  := currSecs / lunarSecs;
  currDays  := Round(currFrac*lunarDays);
  perOfFull := (100*currFrac);


  lb.Items.Add('Date : '+FormatDateTime('dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss',whatDate));
  lb.Items.Add('Lunar days : '+IntToStr(lunarSecs));
  lb.Items.Add('First full 2000 : '+FormatDateTime('dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss',new2000));
  lb.Items.Add('Total seconds : '+IntToStr(totalSecs));
  lb.Items.Add('Current seconds : '+IntToStr(currSecs));
  lb.Items.Add('Current fraction : '+FloatToStr(currFrac));
  lb.Items.Add('Current days : '+IntToStr(currDays));
  lb.items.Add('Percent of full : '+FloatToStr(perOfFull));



end;
```

Comment: @Sjubussen Your math is wrong. You are calculating full moon percentage as a fraction since last full moon cycle. That is not correct. Why? Because full moon percentage doesn't fall down to 0 just after the full moon cycle. Instead full moon percentage starts gradually decreasing after the full moon cycle until it reaches 0 at new moon which is at half of the lunar cycle. In fact you would be better of by using sinusoidal function for calculating full moon percentage.

Comment: Another thing. When calculating lunar cycle always use UTC time and not local time otherwise your results will be sifted by the time difference between UTC and local time.

Answer (score 4):

- I suppose `new2000` is the first new moon in the year 2000? If so then this code should calculate correctly.
- If `new2000` is the full moon, you only have to remove the `-1` in the `cos()` function.

```pascal
uses
    DateUtils;

procedure Calculate();
const
    MoonPeriod = 29.53058770576;
var
    KnownNewMoon: TDateTime;
    NowUTC: TDateTime;
    DaysSinceLastNewMoon, NumberOfNewMoons, MoonPart: Extended;
begin
    KnownNewMoon := EncodeDateTime(2000,1,6,18,14,00,000);
    NowUTC := TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(Now);
    
    //How many moon periods (new moon -> full moon -> new moon) have passed
    //since that known new moon date?
    NumberOfNewMoons := (NowUTC - KnownNewMoon)/MoonPeriod;
    DaysSinceLastNewMoon := Frac(NumberOfNewMoons)*MoonPeriod;
    
    //The "moon part" is a sine/cosine function that starts at new moon with -0,
    //reaches 1 at full moon and goes back to 0 at the next new moon.
    //Starting at cos(-Pi) gives a -1 as "new moon value". Add 1 to set this to 0.
    //Full moon is cos(0) gives 1. With the 1 added before, we have to divide by 2.
    MoonPart := (cos((NumberOfNewMoons*2 - 1) * Pi) + 1)/2;

    lb.items.Add('Number/amount of new moons: '+ FormatFloat('0.000000', NumberOfNewMoons));
    lb.items.Add('Current moon part/position: '+ FormatFloat('0.000000', MoonPart));
    lb.items.Add('Days since last new moon:   '+ FormatFloat('0.000000', DaysSinceLastNewMoon));
end;
```

This should give you the visible moon part in `MoonPart` and the days (incl. fraction) since the last new moon.

Comment: I just read, that the moon period varies by more than 4 hours, so it probably makes no sense, writing the moon period with more than 2 or 3 digits (even if it's an average value).

Comment: Linked sources help. I miss from where OP has his way of calculation, and I'd like to see your source(s), too. It most likely also helps others than just taking this.

Comment: What do you mean by "linked sources"? I only wanted to show a roughly correct method for calculating the visible bright part of the moon based on geometry and physics. Of course that does not include all the errors caused by the moon not really "circling" the earth uninfluenced. I thought I could leave it to the .. is OP "original poster"? to put that into his own code. 
What was missing in my Sources? I had even included the declaration of the used components which you removed.

Comment: [Sources as in "origin(s) of your information"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/source#Noun), not as in "code". How you would prove a paper or article you're about to submit, so everyone is able to read on and reconstruct your conclusions. Yes, ["OP" means "original poster"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/OP#Noun).